# SVM-handwriting-recognition-master

Tags: python, svm

Good day everyone, I am currently working on a project to classify handwriting using SVM classifier, after downloading and resizing the dataset from NIST special database 19. on trying to train my model... I keep getting this error:

```
File "train_model.py", line 65, in <module>
    x_pt = preprocessing.scale(x_pt)
  File "C:\Users\Judson_Morgan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_data.py", line 142, in scale
    force_all_finite='allow-nan')
  File "C:\Users\Judson_Morgan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 586, in check_array
    context))
ValueError: Found array with 0 sample(s) (shape=(0, 144)) while a minimum of 1 is required by the scale function.
```

How do I go about resolving this issue?

Comment: Please add the code of your  ´train_model.py´, otherwise it will be hard to find the error.

Comment: The code is really long but below is the link to the repository i'm working on... The train_model.py is there too.  https://github.com/MarBry111/SVM-handwriting-recognition

Comment: Please Anyone to help with the problem above? Please its really urgent

Comment: No answers yet? Please guys